# Error 1053 : the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion

Tags: c#

My Windows service is suddenly not working and start prompting the the error 1053.

This is my below program in c#

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using EPocalipse.IFilter;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Xml;

namespace MyWindowsService
{
    class Program : ServiceBase
    {

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // If we are in debug mode, start it as a console app
            #if DEBUG
                Program instance = new Program();
                instance.OnStart(null);
                //Console.ReadLine();
                instance.OnStop();
            // If we are NOT in debug mode, start it as a service
            #else
                ServiceBase.Run(new Program());
            #endif
        }

        public Program()
        {
            CanPauseAndContinue = false;
            this.ServiceName = "MySciente Service 2012";
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            base.OnStart(args);
            //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20 * 60 * 1000);
            startMyService();


        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            base.OnStop();
            timer.Enabled = false;
            //sendMail();

        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {

        }

        private void startMyService()
        {
            fileMigration();

            timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
            timer.Interval = (15 * 60 * 1000); //15 is minutes, so here is 15 minutes
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        private void OnElapsedTime(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            fileMigration();
        }

        public static void fileMigration()
        {

            --My Program--

        }


    }
}
```

may i know what is the reason it is causing ? After windows & anti virus update my service causing this issue from last month 15th

Comment: This error happens when onstart method takes too long time to terminate, I suggest that you take a look on event viewer for more info

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `fileMigration()` is taking too long. You should not be performing heavy operations during service startup. I don't know the relationship between those updates you mention and this problem, it could be a coincidence, or perhaps the anti virus now takes more time in their file system hooks, causing `fileMigration()` to take longer.

If you want `fileMigration()` to run at startup, consider using a `Task` or `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` to run it on a separate thread, while informing the operating system about the successful startup early, ie:

```
    private void startMyService()
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(fileMigration);

        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnElapsedTime);
        timer.Interval = (15 * 60 * 1000); //15 is minutes, so here is 15 minutes
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: How to use Task or ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem in my program, give some sample

Comment: @Aravinthan added an example.

Comment: "Not working" you mean it's still reporting "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion"? Are you sure you posted exactly what you are currently using (ie. the `Thread.Sleep()` still commented out?

Comment: @Evenhuis , yes still getting the same error "the service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion". I posted all the code i use in my script.

Comment: @Aravinthan With `fileMigration` moved to another thread, `startMyService()` should finish almost immediately. I can't imagine why this would time out, perhaps you could add some logging in `startMyService()` (with timestamps).